# JSONDecodeError when scraping Twitter data

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, web-scraping, tweepy

So I'm trying to scrape data from Twitter. I manage to retrieve the tweets based on a specific hashtag, and then dump them into a text file in a JSON format using the code below:

```
import json
import tweepy
import pandas as pd
import time

with open('consumer_key.txt', 'r') as f:
    consumer_key =  f.read()
f.closed

with open('consumer_secret.txt', 'r') as f:
    consumer_secret = f.read()
f.closed

with open('access_key.txt', 'r') as f:
    access_key = f.read()
f.closed

with open('access_secret.txt', 'r') as f:
    access_secret = f.read()
f.closed

#Authentication
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True,
             wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True) # Connect to the api

if (not api):
    print ("Error")
    sys.exit(-1)

public_tweets = api.home_timeline() # Get the post in the timeline
for tweet in public_tweets:
    print(tweet.text) 

with open('tweets.txt', 'a') as f:
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='#apple', count=2, lang='en', since='2017-04-03').items():
        json.dump(tweet._json, f, indent=4)
```

However, when I try to read the file using

```
with open('tweets.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        tweet_text = tweet['text']
        print(tweet_text)
```

it gives me an error saying "JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 2 column 1 (char 2)"

This is a snip of my text file:

```
{
    "created_at": "Wed Dec 05 10:37:07 +0000 2018",
    "id": 1070265807492530176,
    "id_str": "1070265807492530176",
    "text": "RT @evankirstel: The Apple Watch Series 3 Made Up Majority of 
Estimated 4.2 Million Q3 2018 Apple Watch Sales #applewatch #apple  
@mactrast\u2026",
    "truncated": false,
    "entities": {
        "hashtags": [
            {
                "text": "applewatch",
                "indices": [
                    110,
                    121
                ]
            },
            {
                "text": "apple",
                "indices": [
                    122,
                    128
                ]
            }
        ],
        "symbols": [],
        "user_mentions": [
            {
                "screen_name": "evankirstel",
                "name": "Evan Kirstel",
                "id": 35203319,
                "id_str": "35203319",
                "indices": [
                    3,
                    15
                ]
            },
            {
                "screen_name": "MacTrast",
                "name": "MacTrast",
                "id": 16711478,
                "id_str": "16711478",
                "indices": [
                    130,
                    139
                ]
            }
        ],
```

How can I solve this? Ultimately, what I want to do is extract data based on the keys and save it in a pandas dataframe.

Comment: You're reading the file line by line and passing each line to json.loads. But a single line of that file does not represent a proper JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

you need to read the whole content not line by line, and don't forget to add `strict=False` to allow/convert `\u2026` to `…`

```
with open('tweets.txt', 'r') as f:
    tweet = json.load(f, strict=False)
    tweet_text = tweet['text']
    print(tweet_text)
```